# Variables in header file, memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, header-files

In iOS, if I put some const variables in a header file then use them in different source files by including this header file, what's the lifecycle of these variables? When are these variables allocated/released? Where are these variables stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> What's the lifecycle of these variables?

The lifecycle of globals is for the life of the app.

> When are these variables allocated/released?

They're not released until the app is terminated.

> Where are these variables stored?

If you're talking about primitive data types or string literals, they're stored in a dedicated `__DATA` segment, not in heap, not in stack.

---

You should not put the implementation of `const` globals in header. Put them in `.m` file. Only put external references to them in the `.h` file.

So, for example, put the following in your `.m` file:

```
NSString * const kNotificationName = @"com.domain.app.notification";
```

And then, in your `.h` file, put:

```
extern NSString * const kNotificationName;
```

That way, you implement it once, but any files that import that header will have visibility to it.

Comment: What's the difference between these 2 approach?

Comment: When are the global variables loaded into memory?

Comment: Regarding the difference b/w these "2 approaches", I assume you're talking about putting the constant implementation in the .h vs putting it in a .m and only having the `extern` reference in the header. The difference is that in the former approach, it will try to create a new constant in every .m file you import the .h file (which will confuse the linker), whereas the latter approach makes it clear that you're creating the actual constant only once, but providing external reference so that any other compilation unit can reference it.

Comment: @jokeman - Re "when" are global constants loaded into memory, they're part of the `__DATA` or `__TEXT` segments loaded when the app is loaded. It's not like your traditional `alloc`/`init` pattern which uses the heap when you encounter it at run time. The compiler builds a "segment" with these constants that is loaded into memory when your app is. For more info on types of memory, WWDC 2012 [App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/242/) is an interesting watch. It shows how things like these constants are handled differently than objects in heap.

Comment: @jokeman - By the way, if you want to see what the compiler does with your constants, you can open up a `.m` file, and then choose "Product" » "Perform Action" » "Assemble Foo.m". It's a bit cryptic if you're not used to seeing assembly code, but you can search for your constant and you'll get some insight as how these constants are represented in your final product.